# How do I make a hyperlink go to a page on another website?

Tags: html, hyperlink

When creating the html files for my website, I had no problem understanding how to create links so that users could navigate between pages. For example, this worked fine to send someone to the about page:

```
<a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
```

I'm having issues upon uploading the html files to my web server.

How, do I get About link to send the user to: www.blahblahblah.com/about ?

My landing page has been renamed index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `http://` in the `href` to go to a page on an external site:

```
<a href="http://www.blahblahblah.com/about">About page on blahblahblah.com</a>
```

This is because when you simply link to it without the `http://` in front (hyper text transfer protocol) it is trying to go to the page "www.blahblahblah.com" which obviously does not eixst on your server. When you add the `http://`, the browser knows that it is another website and therefore will bring you to the external site.

Comment: That works! What do I do, if I'm using the following format?      <input type="button" value="SampleText" onClick="window.location='about.html';">

Comment: @VarunShetty If you are using JavaScript to go to the page (which is what that format is), just do the same thing. Add `http://` if it is an external site. Please remember to click the checkmark on the side of my answer to ["accept" it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/166675) :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your web server will be configured with a "document root" directory. Usually this is the directory where index.html is located. Place your about.html in the same directory, and the link you provided will link to it *if* it is served from the same URL-path (that is to say, it's not in a sub-folder). If your files are indeed in the document root, you may prefix your link href attributes with a forward-slash, which indicates that the path is relative to the document root.

As noted in the previous comment, this technique only works for pages hosted in the same directory as each other, on the same host. If the files are in different directories, you *must* start with the slash, and if they are on different hosts, you must include the full domain and path.

Answer (score 0):

This is what he meant:

```
<input type="button" value="SampleText" onClick="window.location='http://www.blahblahblah.com/about';">
```

and this will open it in a new window:

```
<input type="button" value="SampleText" onclick="window.location='http://www.blahblahblah.com/about';" target="_blank">
```